# Multiple Column write in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I tried writing 2 **`List <WebElement>`** lists to Excel file using Apache POI. But my method only saves the `//column 2` values. `//column 1` data not saved in the excel file.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
public void FourthExcel(String classNameOne,String classNameTwo) {

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
            wait.pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            //Book one
            XSSFWorkbook workbookOne = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheetOne = workbookOne.createSheet("Expenses Sheet");

            CommonClass.sleepTime(3000);

            WebElement expencesTble = driver.findElement(expencesTable);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(expencesTble));

            List<WebElement> ColOneList = driver.findElements(By.className(classNameOne));
            List<WebElement> ColTwoList = driver.findElements(By.className(classNameTwo));

            List<Object> ColOneobjectList = Arrays.asList(ColOneList.toArray());
            List<Object> ColTwoobjectList = Arrays.asList(ColTwoList.toArray());

            int ColumnOneSize = ColOneList.size()-1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= ColumnOneSize; i++) {
                out.println("For");
                out.println(ColOneList.get(i).getText());

                //Column 1
                XSSFRow rowOneColZero = sheetOne.createRow(i);
                rowOneColZero.createCell(0).setCellValue(String.valueOf(ColOneobjectList.get(i)));

                //Column 2
                XSSFRow rowOneCOlOne = sheetOne.createRow(i);
                rowOneCOlOne.createCell(1).setCellValue((RichTextString) ColTwoobjectList.get(i));
            }
            try {
                out.println("try");
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath + "\\testExcel.xls");
                workbookOne.write(fileOut);
                workbookOne.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                out.println(e);

            }
        }
```

The excel file looks like this:

> A1 data is not written into the excel file.

[image]

Comment: Why are you creating the rows twice for each `i`? `Sheet.createRow` creates a new empty row each time it is called. So your `XSSFRow rowOneCOlOne = sheetOne.createRow(i);` will deleting all cells in row `rowOneColZero` which is exactly the same row. Do using only one row for each `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `for` loop You override `XSSFRow` row object, please write like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= ColumnOneSize; i++) {
                    out.println("For");
                    out.println(ColOneList.get(i).getText());

                    //create row
                    XSSFRow row= sheetOne.createRow(i);
                    //to Column 1 
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(String.valueOf( ColOneobjectList.get(i)));        
                    //to Column 2
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue((RichTextString) ColTwoobjectList.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: The code is working perfectly now. But there is a small issue with Excel.
date printing starts with the 3rd row

Comment: Payment Advice [ Accrual Voucher ] 
Payment Advice [ Accrual Voucher ] 13/12/2017
Payment Advice [ Accrual Voucher ] 13/12/2017

Comment: Data should start printing from `0`, maybe initial data in `ColOneobjectList` and `ColTwoobjectList` is an empty string? Add result from excel to your question.